# JAVA - logical operations on chars

Tags: java, char, operators

I am creating a file reading program. I need to filter out any char that is not '0-9' or '.'.

Any char other then these needs to trigger an IF statement.

Here is what I tried -

```
if  ( ( ((char)c < '0') || ((char)c > '9') ) || ((char)c != '.') )
```

or-

```
( ( ((char)c != '0' ) || ((char)c != '.' ) || ((char)c != '1' ) || ((char)c != '2' ) || ((char)c != '3' ) || ((char)c != '4' ) || ((char)c != '5' ) || ((char)c != '6' ) || ((char)c != '7' ) || ((char)c != '8' ) || ((char)c != '9' ) ))
```

neither of which worked.

Comment: If `c` is a character or any other integer type, you should not need the cast there. And you usually would not want to have a floating point number there ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if(Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.')
{

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Any char that is not '.' will cause this if statement to be true, to fix it (and I take the first as an example, but it applies also to the second):

```
 if ( ( ((char)c < '0') || ((char)c > '9') ) && ((char)c != '.') )
```

alternatively, you can write

```
 if (!( ((char)c >='0' && (char) c <='9') || (char) c == '.') )
```